# Styling <a href> tag in the tag itself

Tags: javascript, html, email, html-email

I have a little form for my colleagues that helps them generate their HTML e-mail signature.
The company's leadership has a problem with the link's color in the signature, so I have to figure this out.

The program takes the elements values, puts them in variables, then takes the template of the signature as a long string, and prints it to a different window, putting the variable values to their according place.

Since it is using the template as a string, formatting the  tag in the .css file is not possible. 
I know the method for a:visited, a:unvisited etc etc, but I don't know, how I could use these in the tag "style=" itself.

Does anybody know how this can be done?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why not use a [`<style>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) tag?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, You can not do this, Please read the full reference [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements)

It's not possible, because :visited is pseudo-class and we ca not specify css for a class from inline css [obvious]

What you can do is, write a style tag along with your a tag to specify css

```
<style type="text/css">a:visited {color: red;}</style>
<a href="http://example.com">Example.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you need to specify them in the body tag.

`<body vlink="red">`